# Google Calendar v3 with Umbraco 8

Tags: c#, json.net, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client, umbraco8

So I am trying to add functionality so when I create or update an event page in Umbraco, it will be created or updated in Google Calendar.

But according to the documentation on Google Calendar API I need to install the package "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3" But that requires Newtonsoft version 13.1 at least. But Umbraco 8 only support newtonsoft up to 12.999

So I'm a bit at a loss of what I can do to accomplish this then.

Is it just not possible?

I am trying to follow this guide: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/dotnet?authuser=1#prerequisites

Comment: this is a known issue please go to [google-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues) and report it there.   The more people we have reporting this issue the grater change we have of the team deciding to finally address it.